# Exporting Grails App that is an Eclipse Project as a .war

Tags: eclipse, grails

I have a Grails App that I put together in Eclipse and I need to export it as a .war.  I get an error telling me that I Module Name is Invalid.  Any suggestions on how to do this?  This is my first time using Eclipse.  It seems like something I should have done prior to starting the project.  Is there a way to do it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open shell (command prompt) and navigate to the root of your Grails project. There you can just do: `grails war` that will create .war for you. No need to use Eclipse.